# Angular / Ionic 3 Http.get()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic3

i try to make an `http.get`-Request with `angluar/http` in Ionic 3.
The request is correct, but I'm not able to catch the error.

My methods look like this:

```js
finalize() {
  this.saveConfig().then(() => {
    loader.dismiss();
    loader2.present();
    this.checkApiServer().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      loader2.dismiss();
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('error', err);
      loader2.dismiss();
    });
  });

}

checkApiServer() {
  this.http.get(this.configuration.server + 'ping').subscribe(data => {
    if (data.status == 200) {
      resolve('server available');
    } else {
      reject(Error('server unan'));
    }
  });

}
```

If I'm hitting a correct endpoint everthing works, but if the server is not available, i can not catch the error.

Thank you so much for your help

Greeetings

EDIT:

this is the completed method now:

```js
finalize() {
  this.saveConfig().then(() => {
    loader.dismiss();
    loader2.present();

    this.checkApiServer().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      loader2.dismiss();
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('error', err);
      loader2.dismiss();
      this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
      this.slides.slideTo(1);
      this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
      this.error = true;
      this.errorMessage = 'Der Api-Server konnte nicht erreicht werden. Stellen Sie sicher, dass Sie mit einem WLAN verbunden sind und er korrekte API-Server eingestellt ist.'

    });
  });
}
}

checkApiServer() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.get(this.configuration.server + 'ping', {
      timeout: 3000
    }).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        if (data.status == 200) {
          resolve('server available');
        } else {
          reject(Error('server error'))
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        reject(Error('server unreachable'));
      }
    )
  })
}
```

THANKS!

Comment: What error, from `saveConfig` or from `checkApiServer`?

Comment: there is a syntax error in your example btw

Comment: from `checkApiServer`. Thanks, but @TimothyGroote solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm assuming you're hitting a timeout. you can pass an error handler along with the `subscribe` as an arrow function like this :

```
//timeout is an optional setting optional here
this.http.get(this.configuration.server + 'ping', {headers: headers, timeout: 1000}).subscribe(
    //we only hit this function when the subscribable returns an actual result (in this case, when the server answers)
    (data) => {
      if (data.status == 200) {
        resolve('server available');
      } else {
        reject(Error('server error'));
      }
    },
    //this is the default angular way of handling errors when using a subscribable
    //so it should work for Ionic as well.
    //we will only hit it if something goes wrong while waiting for our subscribable to finish
    (err) => {
      reject(Error('server unreachable?'));
    }
  });
```

Comment: thank you so much. the ``` (err) =>{} ``` was the key.

Answer (score 0):

He, you can use to the new HttpClient module of Angular 4.3, is too easy manage HTTP request.

```
 this.http.get(this.configuration.server, {headers: headers}).subscribe(

        (data) => {
           // Here the code to execute when status code is 200
        },

        (err) => {
          // Here when error
        }, 
() => {
        // and here the code to execute finally, (when http request finish)      
    }
      });
```